# Count the number of words using the given set of keywords in R

Tags: r, text, count, cpu-word

How can I count the number of words in each observation using the given fixed keywords?
To clarify, here is an example.

Here are "Text" and the set of "Keywords"

```
Text=c("I have bought a shirt from the store", "This shirt looks very good")
Keywords=c("have", "from", "good")
```

I would like to obtain the following output.

```
output=c(2,1)
```

In the first sentence in "Text" (i.e., "I have bought a shirt from the store") I observe the "Keywords" two times. "have" and "from." Likewise, in the second sentence in "Text", I observe the "Keywords" once "good."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add word boundaries (`\\b`) to `Keywords` and collapse them into one string to use it in `str_count`.

```
library(stringr)
str_count(Text, str_c('\\b',Keywords, '\\b', collapse = '|'))
#[1] 2 1
```

In base R, you could use `regmatches` + `gregexpr`.

```
lengths(regmatches(Text, gregexpr(paste0('\\b',Keywords, '\\b', collapse = '|'), Text)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this call:
`unlist(lapply(lapply(Text,stringr::str_detect,Keywords),sum))`

`lapply` allows you to apply functions to each element of vector, so this call:

1. applies `str_detect` to each element in Text
2. applies `sum` to each resulting element of `p.1`
3. `unlist` gives you desired vector from the list

Comment: Why not use an anonymous function rather than call `lapply` twice? `sapply(Text,function(x)sum(stringr::str_detect(x,Keywords)))`